# how to apply a function to single data frame column

Tags: r, function

I have a set of models. Each model has has a column `cluster` which is gives each row a  cluster as a categorical variable (with some amount of numbers ranging from 1-120). There is also a column `p.val` with nums ranging from 0-1. I want to print the row with the highest `p.val` value for each of the unique `cluster` values.

The following code does what I want for a single model:

```
for (j in unique(model$cluster))
{
print(j)
print(max(model[model$cluster==j,]$p.val))
}


[1] 2
[1] 0.491592
[1] 3
[1] 0.8446473
[1] 4
[1] 0.49965
[1] 1
[1] 0.7386532
```

How do I write this as a function that allows me to do:

```
func(mod2)
```

I am unfamiliar with writing functions in R and I am running into issues re: when to use apply.

Comment: You don't need a loop, `with(model, tapply(p.val, cluster, FUN = max))` i.e. it is a group by approach.  You may also use `dplyr` i.e. `library(dplyr);model %>% group_by(cluster) %>% summarise(p.val = max(p.val, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop')`

Comment: Or as function `func <- function(dat) {with(dat, tapply(p.val, cluster, FUN = max))}; func(model)`

Comment: apply runs across the row elements of a column or the column elements of a row (based on MARGIN parameter) and applies the function you provide; 
lapply (and sapply) basically don't have the MARGIN parameter but always apply the function across your list elements or in case of data.frame [since a data.frame is 'just' a list of column vectors] across the columns (so as if MARGIN = 2); eg have a look here: https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-tutorial-apply-family